# Relationship between many-to-many table and other one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Good morning to everybody,

First of all, to say that I use Laravel, therefore, Eloquent ORM, but I think it's more of a pure relational database issue (or not), so that's why I mention it here.

For a while, I made a relationship between`many-to-many` table and one-to-many table.

There are these 4 involved tables:

- 'machines' (id, name, ...)
- 'products' (id, name, ...)
- 'machine_products' (id, machine_id, product_id, price).
- 'restrictions' (id, machine_product_id, day, begin_hour, end_hour)

Given a machine and a product in particular, there are N restrictions.

So far, I think everything is fine, but doubts start when I want to translate that into Laravel models.

We would have, in principle, these three models:

- Machine
- Product
- Restriction
- (MachineProduct??? It's not necessary in theory)

Normally, `many-to-many` models do not need to be made since they can be accessed through one of the two main models. In this case, from `Machine` or `Product` we could access the pivot table `machine_products`.

The problem comes when, from an instance of `Machine` or `Product` I want to access, through Eloquent, the `restrictions`. In the same way, I do not know how to access a `Machine` or `Product` through an instance of `restrictions`.

One option, which is the one I chose for now, is this, although it only solves the first problem:

```
Restriction::find(Machine::find(1)->products()->first()->pivot->id);
```

We could suggest a more elegant and practical solution in order to get Restrictions from Product/Machine and backwards?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I want something like that:

`Machine::find(1)->products()->first()->restrictions` or that `Product::find(1)->machines()->first()->[pivot?]->restrictions`.

I would also like to be able to do this: `Restriction::find(1)->[pivot?]->machine` (or product)

Here are the three models:

```
class Machine extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Product', 'machine_products')->withPivot('id','price');
   }
}


class Product extends Model
{  
    public function machines()
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Machine', 'machine_products')->withPivot('price');
    }

}


class Restriction extends Model
{
    // Nothing
}
```

Comment: share your models

Comment: Here, inside comment? Or I edit the post with all three.

Comment: You say you have a "problem" but you it's not clear what it is. The effect of having ORM definitions is creation of certain tables & constraints. You don't just get 2 models & a pivot table from declaring the models, you get that from the models & a M:M declaration. Starting from machines, products & restrictions how are your machine-products or restriction-(machine-product) different from any M:M example you have seen? PS Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Clarify via post edit to a best current form, not via comments.

Comment: I edited the post. What I want, is something like this: `Machine::find(1)->products()->first()->restrictions`. I would also like to be able to do this: `Restriction::find(1)->machine` (or product)

Comment: Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn how to use @ to contact one of multiple non-poster commenters. Your comment notified noone. I wandered by. PS Still no design or MCVE. Where are your Eloquent relationship declarations? Why do expect to have any M:M tables? (Rhetorical.) PS Please don't add EDITs to old versions. Edit your post to be the clearest presentation possible right now.

Comment: Can the `machine_products` table contain multiple rows for a combination of `machine_id` and `product_id`?

Comment: @philipxy sorry, I'm new posting here... The relationship declarations are on my post. The relationships are those: _Given a machine and a product in particular, there are N restrictions_. _Given a Restriction, there are one Machine and one Product_.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No, it can't. Product 1 only could be once for a Machine 1, for example.

Comment: Give a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not recommended (or necessary) to have an `id` column in a pivot table.

I would remove it and adjust the `restrictions` table: `id`, `machine_id`, `product_id`, ...

This accomplishes your second requirement: `Restriction::find(1)->machine`

The reverse direction is still an issue. I think there's just no elegant solution for this:

```php
Restriction::where('machine_id', $machine_id)
    ->where('product_id', $product_id)
    ->get();
```

You could simplify it with a scope:

```php
class Restriction extends Model {
    public function scopeByIds($query, $machine_id, $product_id) {
        $query->where('machine_id', $machine_id)
            ->where('product_id', $product_id);
    }
}

Restriction::byIds($machine_id, $product_id)->get();
```